# Transition matrix, Expected value and Covariance

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\lbrace X_{n} \rbrace _{n}$ a Markov Chain and let $P$ be  the 
associated transition matrix
$P$= $\begin{pmatrix}.2&.3&.5\\.1&.7&.2\\.5&.3&.2\end{pmatrix}$

Given $  P( X_{0}=0)=.4$ and  $ P( X_{0}=1)=P( X_{0}=2)=.3$

Find

$i)$ $E[X_3]$

$ii)$ $P(X_2=0|X_4=1)$

$iii)$ Find $Cov(X,X_3)$

My  attempt to $i)$

First  we need $P^{(3)}$ =$\begin{pmatrix}.236&.468&.296\\.211&.532&.257\\.263&.468&.269\end{pmatrix}$  then we look  for  $E[X_3]$

$E[X]=x_1P(X=x_1)+x_2 P(X=x_2)+x_3P(X=x_3)$ in our case

$E[X_3]=0P(X_3=0)+1 P(X_3=1)+2P(X_3=2)=1 P(X_3=1)+2P(X_3=2)$

$E[X_3]= .4P_{01}^{3}+.3P_{11}^{3}+.3P_{21}^{3} +2[.4P_{02}^{3}+.3P_{12}^{3}+.3P_{22}^{3}]$

Am I   right?

In case of $ii)$ i was planning to compute $P^{(4)}$ THEN ¿$P(X_2=0|X_4=1)=P_{10}^4$? of maybe try for $P(X_2=0|X_4=1)$= $\frac{P(X_2=0,X_4=1)}{P(X_4=1)}$

And for $iii)$ I don't even understand, I think it was a typo mistake  and my teacher wants to refer $Cov(X_i,X_3)$

Any type of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right with case (i). In case (ii) the second formula is valid:
$$
\mathbb P(X_2=0\mid X_4 = 1)=\frac{\mathbb P(X_2=0, X_4 = 1)}{\mathbb P(X_4 = 1)}.
$$
You know how to find the denominator. For numerator we can use
$$
\mathbb P(X_2=0, X_4 = 1) = \mathbb P(X_2=0)\,\mathbb P(X_4=1\mid X_2=0)=\mathbb P(X_2=0) P^{(2)}_{01}.
$$
For (iii) it is typo and we can only suspect what $i$ is given. Say, for 
$$\text{Cov}(X_0, X_3)=\mathbb E[X_0X_3]-\mathbb E[X_0] \mathbb E[X_3]$$
you can repeat calculations from (i).
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X_0X_3] =& 1\cdot 1 \cdot \mathbb P(X_0=1,X_3=1) \cr
+& 1\cdot 2 \cdot \mathbb P(X_0=1,X_3=2)\cr 
+& 2\cdot 1 \cdot \mathbb P(X_0=2,X_3=1)\cr
+& 2\cdot 2 \cdot \mathbb P(X_0=2,X_3=2) \cr
=& \mathbb P(X_0=1)P^{(3)}_{11}+2\mathbb P(X_0=1)P^{(3)}_{12} \cr +&2\mathbb P(X_0=2)P^{(3)}_{21}+4\mathbb P(X_0=2)P^{(3)}_{22}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yes sorry it was a  $0$ insted $i$ thank you so much